# Is there any way to load a JSON file directly into kubernetes environment variables or configmap?

Tags: linux, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have a set of key value pairs in a JSON file that would be mounted in the container. Is there any way to load them directly as environment variables or configmap in Kubernetes directly? I have currently a fallback script to read the file and parse using linux commands, but I am looking for an elegant and/or standard way in Kube to do this. This kube is inside EKS if that is a consideration.

For eg, file;
{key1:value1,key2:value2}

Once done, it should create environment variables like;
echo $key2
value2

Comment: I think you can load entire file as ONE env variable but NOT as the individual keys of the json as different env variables. Meaning ONE env variable `file.json` with the entire json content.

Answer (score 1):

You can load the json file into a configMap and then map it to environment variables in your definition file.

```
kubectl create configmap name-of-your-configmap --from-file=your-file.json
```

Then in your yaml definition file:

```
spec:
  containers:
      ...
      envFrom:
      - configMapRef:
          name: name-of-your-configmap
```